# How to customize the background color of a TTTableViewCell? (Three20 framework)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, three20, tablecell

I am trying to customize the background color of a TTTableViewCell with no success.

I have the following method in my TableViewController which gets executed when the user clicks on a cell :

```
- (void)didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
TTTableViewCell* cell = (TTTableViewCell*) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];}
```

I also tried this

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

but still not working. Any ideas?

Edit: My fault, it is working. I was rendering something on top and I could not see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you are rendering something on top of your cell that doesn't have `[UIColor clearColor]` as background color?

EDIT: Just saw your edit... So obviously... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: I am trying it with no luck. any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm.. I am away from my Mac at the moment - I'll try and have a look after work and update my answer..

Comment: It is working using cell.backgroundColor I have edited my question. Thanks for your help